# Find maximum integer type at runtime in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know if there is a way to find out the maximum, for the sake of having something specific let's say, integer type (or unsigned integer, or float, or complex - any "fixed size" type) supported by `numpy` *at runtime*. That is, let's assume that I *know* (from documentation) that largest unsigned integer type in the *current* version of `numpy` is `np.uint64` and I have a line of code such as:

```
y = np.uint64(x)
```

I would like my code to use whatever is the largest, let's say, unsigned integer type *available in the version of `numpy` that my code uses*. That is, I would be interested in replacing the above hardcoded type with something like this:

```
y = np.largest_uint_type(x)
```

Is there such a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.sctypes`:

```
>>> def largest_of_kind(kind):
...     return max(np.sctypes[kind], key=lambda x: np.dtype(x).itemsize)
... 
>>> largest_of_kind('int')
<class 'numpy.int64'>
>>> largest_of_kind('uint')
<class 'numpy.uint64'>
>>> largest_of_kind('float')
<class 'numpy.float128'>
>>> largest_of_kind('complex')
<class 'numpy.complex256'>
```

Answer (score 3):

While I do like @PaulPanzer solution, I also found that `numpy` defines a function [`maximum_sctype()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/19784177a61de75927a4934fd4cdd91afbb5b35c/numpy/core/numerictypes.py#L143) not documented in `numpy`'s standard docs. This function fundamentally does the same thing as @PaulPanzer solution (plus some edge case analysis). From the code it is clear that `sctype` types are sorted in the increasing size order. Using this function, what I need can be done as follows:

```
y = np.maximum_sctype(np.float)(x) # currently np.float128 on OSX
y = np.maximum_sctype(np.uint8)(x) # currently np.uint64
etc.
```

Comment: Obviously, this is better.

Comment: I've added https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/13054 to rectify the documentation issue. There is no reason this function should be undocumented, especially since it is referenced multiple times in the documentation.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the PR was accepted, so future versions of numpy (presumably starting with 1.17) will have the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but using the prior knowledge that `np.uint` is always an exponent of 2, you can do something like that:

```
for i in range(4,100):
    try:
        eval('np.uint'+str(2**i)+'(0)')
    except:
        c=i-1
        break
answer='np.uint'+str(2**c)

>>answer
Out[657]: 'np.uint64'
```

and you can use it as

```
y=eval(answer+'('+str(x)+')')
```

or, alternatively without the assumption of exp(2) and with no `eval` (check all the numbers up to N, here 1000):

```
 for i in range(1000):
    if hasattr(np,'uint'+str(i)):
        x='uint'+str(i) 

>>x
Out[662]: 'uint64'
```

Comment: This is not a bad attempt. _"...prior knowledge that np.uint is always an exponent of 2..."_ However, this will not work for `float` type on Windows where there is `np.float96`. Also, I would get rid of the `for` loop by setting `i=4` and then using `while True`. This way there is no hardcoded limit on exponent `i`.

Comment: man you asked about `uint` types... if you have a better way I will be happy to hear.

Comment: Using `eval` here is unnecessary and a bad habit; you could just make `hasattr` checks for whether the `numpy` module has the attributes you're interested in, and `getattr` to retrieve the type.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to use `uint` as an example. I will edit my question.

Comment: I know you are trying to help and I am grateful. However, as you say this solution, unfortunately, is not elegant: first, because of these trials an a loop, second because `hasattr()` is a relatively slow function, and finally because there is a hard limit on the exponent.